# how to test a graphene mutation with **kwargs on mutate function?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, graphene-python

I am testing a mutation that creates a user something like this:

```
def test_create_user(self):
    user_mutation = """
        mutation($id: ID!, $group: GroupInput!, $address: AddressInput!){
            createUser(id: $id, group: $group, address: $address) {
                user {
                    id
                }
            }
        }
    """

    group = {
        'name': 'GroupA',
        'contact': '1231323131'
    }
    address = {
        'street': '123',
        'city': 'Test City'
    }

    resp = self.client.execute(user_mutation,
                               variable_values={
                                   'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
                                   'group': group,
                                   'address': address
                               })
```

The Mutation Class:

```
class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.String(required=True)
        group = GroupInput(required=True)
        address = AddressInput(required=True)
        ...more input here

    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    def mutate(self, info, **kwargs):
        user = create_user(**kwargs)
        return CreateUser(user=user)
```

The problem is that when I try to run this test is it return an error:

```
test_create_user {'errors': [{'message': "create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'", 'locations': [{'line': 4, 'co
lumn': 25}], 'path': ['createUser']}], 'data': OrderedDict([('createUser', None)])}
```

I'm not sure how should I go about this and I use **kwargs** because there is much more input to be added here. Any ideas and suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The default `User` model seems to have a [`groups` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups) instead of `group`. Are you using a custom `User` model?

Comment: Can you add the `create_user` function to the question as well.